# iOSBetaBuilder + screen flash

Tags: ios, distribution, adhoc

Hi I am using iOS Beta Builder to create a wifi distribution for my iOS devices. It installs fine on the devices, but when I launch the application the screen flashes and it crashes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The screen flash and crash behavior is typical when an iOS app tries to launch without a proper distribution profile. iOS Beta Builder does not remove the need for the distribution profile, it just makes loading versions of the app easier. Check that the device is covered by the distribution profile used during the code signing phase of building the app.